# How do I implement an image array in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, image

I'm trying to create an array of images for an imageView and then change those images when a button is pressed. I'm just testing the ability for the button to cause a method to get and display the image from the array. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I have so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Image1.JPG", @"Image2.JPG", nil];
}


-(IBAction)img1 {

    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
}
```

I also get the warning 'unused variable 'imagesArray'

Thanks for helping!

Comment: 'unused variable "imagesArray"'.. Think twice. You probably haven't used it yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not retaining `NSMutableArray *imagesArray`, it goes out of scope as soon as viewDidLoad completes.

try this:

declare instance variable `NSMutableArray *imagesArray;`

and init using

```
imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Image1.JPG", @"Image2.JPG", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you declared your array twice. Change your load method to this and try again.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Image1.JPG", @"Image2.JPG", nil];

}
```